# need to backspace twice before div closes on .length==0 , although backspace twice on phone wont hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to backspace twice for the :

```
if (str.length==0) { }
```

to work.
Although on a mobile phone when I backspace twice it wont hide the div. I am wondering how I can resolve this issue. The code seems fairly simple when the string length is 0 e.g empty it should hide the div although it does not?

```
function showResult(str) {
if (str.length==0) {
$("#livesearcher").hide();
} else {
$("#livesearcher").show();
$("#livesearcher").load('inc/search_res.php?q='+str);
}
}
```

This is how I call the function :

```
<input type='text' name='q' value='' maxlength='255' onkeydown='showResult(this.value)' id='searcherin' autocomplete='off'>
```

Comment: And how do you call this function??? Which DIV are you talking about? Couldn't you provide relevant code in question? What about a jsfiddle?

Comment: <input type='text' name='q'  value='' maxlength='255'  onkeydown='showResult(this.value)' id='searcherin' autocomplete='off'/>
thats how i call the function

Comment: and i'm talking about the livesearcher div..

Comment: Post code in question, not as comment, thank you!

Comment: As i see it, you should use onkeyup instead

Comment: onkeyup worked perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onkeydown` is fired *before* the textbox's value updates, therefore it still has whatever was there before.

Use `onkeyup` instead.

However it should be noted that many mobile browsers do not fire `onkey*` events on inputs, and you should use `onchange` instead.

Comment: good point about mobile. Just asking if you know the answer but what about oninput on mobile? Is it fired while user is filling the field?